# What's the proper way to do MongoDB aggregation query with optional parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this api endpoint where i want to lookup a user or multiple users schedule and also specify the month or/and the day when doing the query. My code works, but i feel like there is a better, cleaner way to do this.

From the frontend i do a get request that has the following query params.

```
http://localhost:5000/api/schedule/?name=John Doe&name=Sam Smith&month=July 2020&day=Wed Jul 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300
```

then this api controller will take the req.query obj and use it to do a custom query. I wanted the options like month or day to be optional and still get a result if they are omitted.

```
    exports.find_by_query = async (req, res) => {
      let day;
      let month;
      let name;
      const query = [{ $match: {} }];
      const filter = { name: {} };
    
      if (req.query.name) {
        name = req.query.name;
        filter.name = { $in: name };
        query[0].$match = filter;
      }
    
      if (req.query.day) {
        const date = new Date(req.query.day);
        date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        day = date.toString().split("(Eastern European Summer Time)")[0].trim();
      }
    
      if (req.query.month) {
        month = req.query.month;
      }
    
       if (month !== undefined && day === undefined) {
    query.push({
      $group: {
        _id: `$shifts.${month}`,
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        result: { $push: { name: "$name" } },
      },
    });
  }
  if (day !== undefined) {
    query.push({
      $group: {
        _id: `$shifts.${month}.${day}`,
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        result: { $push: { name: "$name", shift: `$shifts.${month}.${day}` } },
      },
    });
  }
      
    
      Schedule.aggregate(query, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(user);
      });
    };
```

This is what the returned json looks like for one user, without specifying the month or day.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f00b12a1607ad69f866cc49",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "shifts": {
            "July 2020": {
                "Wed Jul 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300": {
                    "start": "09:00 AM",
                    "end": "06:00 PM"
                },
                "Thu Jul 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300": {
                    "start": "09:00 AM",
                    "end": "06:00 PM"
                },
                "Fri Jul 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300": {
                    "start": "09:00 AM",
                    "end": "06:00 PM"
                },
                "Sat Jul 04 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300": {
                    "start": "DO",
                    "end": "DO"
                },
```

So while this works, i feel that there's too many steps and doesn't look readable enough.

**EDIT: I modified the original code so that i get something more organize sent back to the req. I'm only interested in getting back the names with their schedule and not the other fields. It looks very messy IMO but i don't know how else to clean it up.**

```
exports.find_by_query = async (req, res) => {
  let day;
  let month;
  let name;
  const query = [{ $match: {} }];
  const filter = { name: {} };

  if (req.query.name) {
    name = req.query.name;
    filter.name = { $in: name };
    query[0].$match = filter;
  }

  if (req.query.day) {
    const date = new Date(req.query.day);
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    day = date.toString().split("(Eastern European Summer Time)")[0].trim();
  }

  if (req.query.month) {
    month = req.query.month;
  }
  //code to get all in results
  // count: { $sum: 1 },
  // result: { $push: "$$ROOT" }

  if (month !== undefined && day === undefined) {
    query.push({
      $group: {
        _id: { name: "$name", shift: `$shifts.${month}` },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        result: { $push: { name: "$name" } },
      },
    });
  }
  if (day !== undefined) {
    query.push(
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { name: "$name", shift: `$shifts.${month}.${day}` },
          // count: { $sum: 1 },
          // result: {
          //   $push: { name: "$name", shift: `$shifts.${month}.${day}` },
          // },
        },
      },
      { $sort: { "_id.source": 1 } }
    );
  }

  console.log(query);

  Schedule.aggregate(query, function (err, user) {
    count = 0;
    result = [];
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    for (let i of users) {
      if (i._id.shift.start) {
        if (i._id.shift.start === "DO" || i._id.shift.start === "CO") {
          result.push({
            [i._id.name]: i._id.shift.start,
          });
        } else {
          result.push({
            [i._id.name]: `${i._id.shift.start} - ${i._id.shift.end}`,
          });
        }
      } else {
        result.push({ [i._id.name]: [] });
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(i._id.shift)) {
          if (value.start === "DO" || value.start === "CO") {
            result[count][i._id.name].push({
              [key]: value.start,
            });
          } else {
            result[count][i._id.name].push({
              [key]: `${value.start} - ${value.end}`,
            });
          }
        }
        count++;
      }
    }
    res.json(result);
  });
};
```

With this query `http://localhost:5000/api/schedule/?month=July 2020&day=Wed Jul 06 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300` will return this:

```
[
    {
        "user1": "09:00 AM - 04:00 PM"
    },
    {
        "user2": "09:00 PM - 01:00 AM"
    },
    {
        "user3": "DO"
    },
    {
        "user4": "DO"
    },
    {
        "user5": "12:00 AM - 09:00 AM"
    },
    {
        "user6": "DO"
    },
```

which is exactly what i wanted. If i leave the day out and specify only the month, i get back their schedule for every day of the month in the above format. This data will be easier to use on my frontend but i wish the code to make it work was cleaner, more readable, maybe less steps.

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel, use libraries like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/). It makes your life much easier.